# Javascript Alert Repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am writing a script to prevent people from being able to right click on an image. Once they click on the image I have set a Alert box to show to state that the images are copyrighted. To try and explain how this works, the image is in a model that doesnt appear in the DOM until another ID is clicked (done through AJAX). The script I have waits till the ID is clicked and the model loads, and then executes the function to show the Alert if there is a right click. The issue is, there are multiple buttons that can be clicked on to make the model appear, and so, in my code I targeted each of them, and if any of them are clicked, the function fires. The issue happens when you click the ID to make the model appear, close the model, and then click another ID to make the same model appear. When this is done, the alert shows multiple times. And so, if you spend some time clicking on all the IDs that fire the function, when you eventually right click the image, the alert may show 10-20 times. I am looking for a way to make the alter only show once, no matter how many times the function is executed.

My script is below:

```
function imageClickerz( ) {
    $( "#sb-wrapper-inner" ).each(function( index ) {
         $('#sb-wrapper-inner, #sb-nav-previous, #sb-nav-next').mousedown(function(event) { 
            switch (event.which) {
            case 3:
                    alert('Sorry, our images are copyrighted.');
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
}
$("#product_photo").hover(function(){
  setTimeout(function (){
       $('div[id^=vZoomMagnifier], img[id^=alternate_product_photo_], .vCSS_img_product_photo, .vCSS_img_larger_photo, #product_photo, #sb-nav-previous, #sb-nav-next, ').click(function(event){
        setTimeout(function (){
          imageClickerz( )
          }, 800); 
        });
   }, 100); 
});
```

Comment: *I am writing a script to prevent people from being able to right click on an image.* People have been doing that for *decades* now and have always failed. It's 2015, you can give up now. Happy new year.

Comment: Blocking right clicks is invasive and annoying, use a canvas instead

Comment: Don't forget to block screenshots!

Comment: Even if a part of the users can circumvent this protection, I still would say that it will block the majority of users or at least make them think that it isn't ok to save these images. It does decrease the likelihood of image theft even if disabling context menu will mainly give a false sense of safety.

Comment: Just a thought...Put the image as a `CSS` background on a `<div>`, then if the user right clicks they are never given the option to download the image. You can try this on the StackOverflow logo.

Comment: If they want the image, they will get it. Might give someone peace of mind, but it will be founded on false understandings

Comment: Thanks guys. And yes, I know that this will not stop anyone who REALLY wants the images. I just needed to add the alert (its what the boss people want). And in regards to just putting the image in the CSS, unfortunately I do not have the power to do that :/

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely want to grab context events, it's better to trust that rather than right click since it will also include touch events (e.g. holding down the touch to get the context)

```
$('#sb-wrapper-inner').on('ContextMenu contextmenu oncontextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Sorry, our images are copyrighted.');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: There is really very little that you can do but to tease the users. I would advice to fail silently (leaving that annoying `alert` completely away), but at least this will give a nice false sense of safety.

Comment: This looks like it would be the best way to go, however I cant seem to get this to work. You can see the site I am working on here, it just a site set up for testing: http://v1643013.pexsoq4d3kas.demo11.volusion.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=CLVN

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing an alert and using JavaScript, place a div on top of the picture, just as effective but less invasive. Just by the way, you simply cannot stop people from downloading anything they can see on your website..

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".sb-wrapper-inner.protected" ).on('contextmenu', function(event) {
  switch (event.which) {
    case 3:
      alert('Sorry, our images are copyrighted.');
      event.preventDefault();
      break;
  }
});
```

you can have a look to this HTML snippet also, might look like your's

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sb-wrapper-inner protected">
  <img src="http://www.lftechnology.com/media/images/home_feature_notebook_bg.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="sb-wrapper-inner">
    <img src="http://www.lftechnology.com/media/images/clients_interac.png" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="sb-wrapper-inner protected">
  <img src="http://www.lftechnology.com/media/images/home_feature_notebook_bg.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[the respective code pen link is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwGJBw?editors=101)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how I corrected the issue: I set a global variable to 0, and then set the variable to 2 once the function is called. If the the variable is equal to either 0 or 2, then the code in the function will run fine. I then surrounded the other click events with a if statement so they would only run the function if the variable was 0. Therefore preventing the function from being called multiple times, and allowing the pop up to show every time the image is right clicked.

```
var clicked = 0;
function imageClickerz( ) {
    if(clicked === 0 || 2) {
         $('#sb-wrapper-inner, #sb-nav-previous, #sb-nav-next').mousedown(function(event) {
            switch (event.which) {
            case 3:
                    confirm('Sorry, our images are copyrighted.');
                    break;
            }
        clicked = 2;
        });
    }
}
$("#product_photo").hover(function(){
  setTimeout(function (){
       $('div[id^=vZoomMagnifier]').click(function(event){
        setTimeout(function (){
                  if (clicked === 0 ) {
          imageClickerz( )
                  } else {console.log("its done dude")}
          }, 800); 
        });
   }, 100); 
});
$('img[id^=alternate_product_photo_], .vCSS_img_product_photo, .vCSS_img_larger_photo, #product_photo, #sb-nav-previous, #sb-nav-next, ').click(function(event){
        setTimeout(function (){
                  if (clicked === 0 ) {
          imageClickerz( )
                  } else {console.log("its done dude")}
          }, 800); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a variable `var hasSeenAlert = false` before all those functions.  Then set up your mousedown function callback to only execute if `hasSeenAlert` is false.

```
$('#sb-wrapper-inner, #sb-nav-previous, #sb-nav-next').mousedown(function(event) { 
    if(hasSeenAlert === false){
        switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
                alert('Sorry, our images are copyrighted.');
                break;
        }
        hasSeenAlert = true
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem here is that the alert will only show once. If you click okay and then right click again, hasSeenAlert will be true, and the function will not fire. Thanks though!